# Is it standard web-browser behaviour to prepend the current URL to incomplete links?

Tags: html, url, web, browser, href

If a website includes an incomplete link such as the following:

```
<a href="#my_div">Link</a>
<a href="?my_var=1">Link</a>
```

Is it standard, universal behaviour that the link would be interpreted as the current URL with the **href** value appended to it?

Comment: How else would it possibly be interpreted?

Comment: Not necessarily the current URL.  It's a little more accurate to say that it take its place after the hostname (or origin or whatever) and the path.  For instance, a link with an href of `?my_var=1` on a document that currently has a full url of `http://stackoverflow.com?some_var=2` will direct you to `http://stackoverflow.com?my_var=1`.  It would completely replace the original location search/query value with the `my_var=1` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The HTML5 spec defines how `[href]` attributes behave](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-href)

> The href attribute on a and area elements must have a value that is a [valid URL potentially surrounded by spaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-url-potentially-surrounded-by-spaces).

which links to:

> A string is a valid URL potentially surrounded by spaces if, after stripping leading and trailing whitespace from it, it is a [valid URL](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-url).

which links to:

> A URL is a valid URL if it conforms to the authoring conformance requirements in the URL standard. [[URL](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/references.html#refsURL)]

which links to a sizable block of text, but I think the following is important:

> Most of the URL-related terms used in the HTML specification (URL, absolute URL, relative URL, relative schemes, scheme component, scheme data, username, password, host, port, path, query, fragment, percent encode, get the base, and UTF-8 percent encode) can be straightforwardly mapped to the terminology of [RFC3986] [RFC3987].

---

As for the "incomplete link" examples you included in your question. They are examples of a "fragment" and "query" respectively, which have an implicit relative URL of `.` which represents the current URL (*note that it will not merge query strings or document fragment identifiers*).